# Optimisation exercise in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to automatically fill in a form with '0' if there is no value supplied. There are 14 questions to be filled in. The code I've written is ugly but works.  I am looking to improve it by setting an array with all the questions and loop the command untill all the boxes are filled in with values or 0.

```
if ($q1 == '') {
                    $q1 = '0';
                  }
                    if ($q2 == '') {
                      $q2 = '0';
                  }
                  if ($q3 == '') {
                    $q3 = '0';
                  }
                  if ($q4 == '') {
                    $q4 = '0';
                  }
                            //... and so on up to $q14

                  if ($q13 == '') {
                    $q13 = '0';
                  }
                  if ($q14 == '') {
                    $q14 = '0';
                  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should be using an array for these variables. Then you could simply loop through the indexes of the array to test and change as required. If you cannot change that, you can use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to simplify the code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++) {
    if (${"q$i"} == '') ${"q$i"} = 0;
}
```

If you do put the values in an array, you can loop through it with a `foreach`. Note the use of `&$v` to allow us to change the value in the loop:

```
foreach ($q as &$v) {
    if ($v == '') $v = 0;
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GUKpn)